# Unable to understand errors when i run the command 'python manage.py migrate'

Tags: django, postgresql-9.6

I have been following Django girls tutorial to learn Django web framework. 
I have reached [this part](https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/optional_postgresql_installation/) of the tutorial. Now I am completely stuck when I run the command `python manage.py migrate`.
I cannot even run my server on the local host anymore, runserver brings the same error. All these errors started coming up since I changed my settings.py file to accommodate the Postgres database.
I am in dire need of some help.

I had postgres installed from before(version 11.4). Seeing these errors I removed it, and then downloaded it again, following the directions of the aforementioned tutorial. It was a useless effort, as the same problem came up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/home/jpsofficedev/Documents/coding_for_girls/djangogirls/myvenv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()  File "/home/jpsofficedev/Documents/coding_for_girls/djangogirls/myvenv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)  File "/home/jpsofficedev/Documents/coding_for_girls/djangogirls/myvenv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 168, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/jpsofficedev/Documents/coding_for_girls/djangogirls/myvenv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "jpsofficedev"
```

database settings in settings.py

```
      'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'djangogirls',
        'USER': 'jpsofficedev',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

For a better understanding of what i have done, I am providing link to my github profile for this project.
https://github.com/bhawanabadlani/my-first-blog

My experience in Postgres is null. Suggestions for some tutorial, documentation will also be appreciated.

[this is my pg_hba.conf file. Is there some problem in it's settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcbwE.png)

Comment: This "https://www.depesz.com/2007/10/04/ident/" may help you!

Comment: please show your database settings in settings.py

Comment: please check this https://serverfault.com/questions/406606/postgres-error-message-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user

Comment: The issue is with the connection to your database. The link above from Deepak will help you resolve the issue. Either you haven't correctly defined the role for your jpsofficedev user or your authentication setting is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback. I will try to resolve the issues from the links given. I have also shown database settings in my settings.py. I have even provided link to my project uploaded at GitHub. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

thankyou for the link @DEEPAK KUMAR
https://serverfault.com/questions/406606/postgres-error-message-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user.
I followed this link, and changed

`host all all 127.0.0.1/32 ident`

to

`host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust`
 in pg_hba.conf file. This resolved the issues I was facing.